# Find number between $A$ and $B$ with maximum set bits?

Tags: binary, binary-operations

Given two integers $A,B$.
Find number $N$ which has maximum number of set bits in its binary form and lies between $A$ and $B$ inclusive.
Is there any approach for this question.
Also if there are multiple possible answers I want $N$ to be smallest of those.

Comment: What are your thoughts? For example if $A=100101101_2$ and $B=100100110_2$, how would you attack the problem by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

Suppose the upper $k$ bits of $A,B$ match. Then for any $x$ satisfying
$A \le x \le B$, the upper $k$ bits of $x$ will match those of $A,B$. You can
do nothing about those except count them.

So, suppose the top bit of $A$ is 0 and the corresponding bit of $B$ is 1 
(and both have $n$ bits). Then you should find a number in the range
$A,...,B$ such that $N \ge n-1$.

There is only one possibility remaining after that.